# Assessing effectiveness of (epsilon, delta) definitions

Tags: soft-question, real-analysis, mathematics-education, teaching, mathematical-philosophy

There is much discussion both in the education community and the mathematics community concerning the challenge of (epsilon, delta) type definitions in calculus and the student reception of them. The mathematical community often holds an upbeat opinion on the success of student reception of this (see examples below), whereas the education community often stresses difficulties and their "baffling" and "inhibitive" effect (see below). A typical educational perspective on this was recently expressed by Paul Dawkins in the following terms:

> 2.3. Student difficulties with real analysis definitions. The concepts of limit and continuity have posed well-documented difficulties for students both at the calculus and analysis level of instructions (e.g. Cornu, 1991; Cottrill et al., 1996; Ferrini-Mundy & Graham, 1994; Tall & Vinner, 1981; Williams, 1991). Researchers identified difficulties stemming from a number of issues: the language of limits (Cornu, 1991; Williams, 1991), multiple quantification in the formal definition (Dubinsky, Elderman, & Gong, 1988; Dubinsky & Yiparaki, 2000; Swinyard & Lockwood, 2007), implicit dependencies among quantities in the definition (Roh & Lee, 2011a, 2011b), and persistent notions pertaining to the existence of infinitesimal quantities (Ely, 2010). Limits and continuity are often couched as formalizations of approaching and connectedness respectively. However, the standard, formal definitions display much more subtlety and complexity. That complexity often baffles students who cannot perceive the necessity for so many moving parts. Thus learning the concepts and formal definitions in real analysis are fraught both with need to acquire proficiency with conceptual tools such as quantification and to help students perceive conceptual necessity for these tools. This means students often cannot coordinate their concept image with the concept definition, inhibiting their acculturation to advanced mathematical practice, which emphasizes concept definitions.

See [the entire article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmathb.2013.10.002) (note that the online article provides links to the papers cited above).

To summarize, in the field of education, researches decidedly have *not* come to the conclusion that epsilon, delta definitions are either "simple", "clear", or "common sense". Meanwhile, mathematicians often express contrary sentiments. Two examples are given below.

> ...one cannot teach the concept of limit without using the epsilon-delta definition. Teaching such ideas intuitively does not make it easier for the student it makes it harder to understand. Bertrand Russell has called the rigorous definition of limit and convergence the greatest achievement of the human intellect in 2000 years! The Greeks were puzzled by paradoxes involving motion; now they all become clear, because we have complete understanding of limits and convergence. Without the proper definition, things are difficult. With the definition, they are simple and clear.

see Kleinfeld, Margaret; Calculus: Reformed or Deformed? Amer. Math. Monthly 103 (1996), no. 3, 230-232.

> I always tell my calculus students that mathematics is not esoteric: It is common sense. (Even the notorious epsilon, delta definition of limit is common sense, and moreover is central to the important practical problems of approximation and estimation.)

see Bishop, Errett; Book Review: Elementary calculus. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 83 (1977), no. 2, 205--208.

Having presented some published references, I would like to complement the published references with anecdotal evidence drawn from this very page, namely the sentiment that

> epsilon-delta definition is immediately appealing to students with a certain clarity of mind, etc.

Such sentiments I believe are common and reveal a belief that these convoluted definitions are "natural" and a failure to follow them possibly constitutes an absence of a "clarity of mind".

When one compares the upbeat assessment found in the mathematics community and the somber assessments common in the education community, sometimes one wonders whether they are talking about the same thing. How does one bridge the gap between the two assessments? Are they perhaps dealing with distinct student populations? Are there perhaps education studies providing more upbeat assessments than Dawkins' article would suggest?

Note 1. A number of editors have commented by now on the subject of alternatives. Thus, Neil Strickland notes that "People may think that rigorous analysis is valuable despite this [teaching difficulty], and that certain other proposed teaching methods are no better, but those are different questions." In response, I would like to mention that the comparison of distinct approaches to teaching analysis is a fascinating subject, on which I have first hand experience and much to say. However, this subject is not that of this *question*.

Note 2. Evidence from classroom experience comparing the two approaches has been presented in [this recent publication](http://dx.doi.org/10.5642/jhummath.201701.07) based on the opinion poll of the students involved.

Comment: The fact that this circle of ideas can be difficult and discouraging is one of its good features, insofar as it aids in the early identification and weeding-out of students who don't have an aptitude for math.

Comment: Katz I feel like many of your questions are thinly disguised attempts to push an agenda about infinitesimals, which I don't think is really in the spirit of the site.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: don't ask me for a teaching reference letter.

Comment: @BenMcKay, please, I don't want this closed as "subjective and argumentative". I think Steve's comment was tongue-in-cheek. I am sure he is a fine pedagogue.

Comment: @katz:  Obviously this is not the place for a continued discussion, but for the record I was entirely serious and I am baffled as to why you thought otherwise.

Comment: @Steve, then you appear to agree with the education community about the difficulty of the material. If so the question remains to understand why the mathematics community often views it differently (a number of recent discussions at MO testify to this).

Comment: I think many of the difficulties with $\epsilon-\delta$ or $\epsilon-N$ analysis disappear when they are properly motivated.  How many terms do you need in the Riemann sum to get an approximation with a maximum error of $0.001$?  This is question is not esoteric at all:  it is essential if you are going to numerically integrate anything in the real world.

Comment: @katz: what is this "upbeat assessment" of which you speak?  I don't think I have heard many people deny that average students find rigorous analysis hard, and that current teaching methods do not succeed in making many of them understand it.  People may think that rigorous analysis is valuable despite this, and that certain other proposed teaching methods are no better, but those are different questions.

Comment: All answers (so far) are opinions, leading to the suggestion to close the question...

Comment: @NeilStrickland, a good example of such an "upbeat assessment" is the comment by Steven Gubkin above. You just have to "properly motivate" it and the difficulties magically "disappear". Gubkin (and many others who have expressed similar sentiments) may well be right about this. However, the question still remains why there is such a different perception in the education community and the mathematical community. Could it be that in the education community they just have not caught on to the fact that definitions have to be "properly motivated"? I note that Gubkin's comment got 5 uparrows so far

Comment: A mathoverflow comment together with five upvotes does not convince me of the existence of a consensus in the mathematical community, particularly when my personal experience is that most mathematicians recognize students' difficulties in real analysis.  I would consider a vote to re-open the question if you could justify the phrase "...upbeat assessment common in the mathematics community..." as well as you justified "...somber assessments common in the education community..."  Otherwise it is hard to imagine an answer based on something other than personal opinion.

Comment: I agree whole-heartedly with @PaulSiegel and Neil Strickland, and find this yet another example of the OP extrapolating anecdote or personal experience into universal truth. Are we taking the USA as representative of all mathematics education here?

Comment: @Paul, I provided some examples.

Comment: @katz:  I am not saying that $\epsilon-\delta$ analysis is easy.  It takes special training to understand statements with that many quantifiers.  My point is that it is that $\epsilon-\delta$ should not be taught simply as a way to "back up" intuition with "rigorous proofs", but that in fact it is very important to develop an understanding of error analysis.  As a practical skill, this is probably more important to the engineer or scientist than manipulating mathematical symbols formally:  symbolic calculators can integrate or differentiate a lot better than humans can.

Comment: It is also an opportunity to give students the exposure to these difficult modes of thought.  Just because something is hard is not an excuse to avoid it!  Things which are valuable are often difficult.

Comment: @StevenGubkin, my question was not to determine whether these definitions are difficult or easy, but to point out a difference in perception in the two communities. I provided some examples to illustrate the point. I certainly agree with you that epsilon, delta definitions are an essential part of the subject and should not be avoided (I can't see how anybody can disagree with that!).

Comment: @katz I do not think that there is a difference between the two communities.  These examples are cherry picked.  I am sure that if you polled mathematicians with the question "Is it easy for most freshman students to understand $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit", you would find that overwhelmingly they would say no.  They might not have given a great deal of thought as to why, but they would say no.  In my responses above I am merely pointing out that it becomes less difficult if you devote a significant amount of time to it, and this time is justified by the necessity of error analysis.

Comment: The first two sentences of the quote from Kleinfeld are a good example.  The reference to Russell and the quote from Bishop both show the response of mathematicians rather than the response of mathematics students.

Comment: Russell and Bishop are both lacking much context. Since they both attempted to provide some kind of rigorous foundation for mathematics, it's natural that they would talk this way about a rigorous definition. It is also clear that they are not representative of mathematicians in general. Additionally, I doubt Russell ever taught anything one would recognize as calculus. Bishop did teach calculus but that is not the point of view he is representing in his review of Keisler's book.

Comment: @François, I agree with your comments on Russell.  My point here was to respond to a request by a fellow editor to provide citations from mathematicians, which I did by citing Kleinfeld, Margaret (who happens to quote Russell, but this is less relevant). I don't think Bishop's thinking about "common sense" is atypical in the math community. Can you cite an education specialist that thinks that epsilon, delta are "common sense" or "simple" (that is, before one masters the technique)?

Comment: The point is that the reason why Bishop calls the epsilon-delta definition "common sense" is because of his constructivist agenda. It is misleading to use this quote without this context and it is inappropriate to cite him as representative of mathematicians in general.

Comment: @katz You should consider re-asking this question at matheducators.stackexchange.com

Comment: @StevenLandsburg, I agree with you that this material serves as a useful filter to weed out the weak students.  However I think the material remains challenging even based on Keisler or related approaches using infinitesimals, so the role of a useful filter remains and is somewhat irrelevant to this *question*.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: yes, that's a fair point.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the key difficulty lies in the use of two quantifiers. I think when we teach calculus, we usually do not verify that students have a clear understanding of each quantifier alone. So when we string two of them together, they are totally lost. What students need is a strong grasp of the deductive logic involved. Unfortunately, I do not know how to teach this effectively.

Comment: @MikhailKatz - Putting aside the question of representativeness, I do not understand how you are reading Bishop as asserting that epsilon, delta is common sense *before one masters the technique*. The quote given in the OP is preceded by "Although it seems to be futile..." and followed with "They do not believe me." It seems clear even Bishop does not think students take to the definition easily or naturally.

Comment: I have posted an answer arguing that the disagreement is illusory at matheducators.SE https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/16857/140

Answer (score 9):

I would attribute this to **sample bias** -- which is "distinct student populations" of a sort.

Mathematicians who teach epsilon-delta definitions rarely study student reception of those definitions in a rigorous way.  If they did, they would probably be publishing in education journals, not math journals.

Math teachers evaluating the reception of these ideas probably make **informal evaluations, focusing on the most obvious students**:  those who participated actively in class, those who stayed in touch with their teachers, those who continued with more mathematics.  Those students are substantially more likely to appreciate the epsilon-delta definitions.

Education researchers are less likely to suffer from this bias, though surely they suffer from others.

Comment: This is an interesting hypothesis. If you are in touch with some education specialists, could you ask around to see if there are studies that could confirm the idea of "sample bias"?

Answer (score 8):

I don't teach calculus, but I think what really gives students trouble are nested universal and existential quantifiers --- not epsilons and deltas in particular. I teach these in the language of adversarial games between two players. Usually, "for all" is the adversary, who gets to choose any object, so we must be prepared for "the worst". "There exists" is the "me" player, who must provide *some* response to the adversary's challenge. Additional levels of nesting correspond to multiple game rounds. I also instruct my students to read quantified formulas from the inside-out: First understand the "last move" in the game and slowly make your way to the beginning. For my small sample size, this seems to be an effective technique.

Comment: I've used this in a Calculus classroom.  It seems to be very illuminating to some students, and mean almost nothing to others.  All in all, I think it helps enough students that it's worth the time it takes to explain and work out a few examples.

Comment: The problem I've encountered is that the roles switch once you *use* continuity rather than *proving* it:  for a function that is assumed continuous, the "for all" player is me, and the "there exists" player is an oracle who supplies the crucial ingredient in my proof.

Answer (score 7):

To bridge that gap, I think that math departments in introductory analysis should be showing and motivating as many alternative definitions of the derivative and the integral as they can. Considering hypothetical or alternate definitions exercises one's intuition muscles, and it helps address some of the common hang-ups that some of the students tend to get caught in. I favor doing epsilon-delta side by side with the infinitesimal approach just so the students can experience the differences in conceptualization.

If time is limited, it is better even to emphasis definition and theorem than the actual proofs themselves. One of the main goals of introductory proof making courses should be to prepare students to ask intelligent and critical questions when they are presented with abstract theoretical propositions, rather than being dependent on an instructor to spoon feed them.

Many physics students enter graduate programs unprepared for conceptualization and intuition because they lack the basic motivation and building blocks for thinking in terms of definition, theorem, and proof. One result has been physics departments filled with instructors who can't even explain the basic justification for manipulations they do on the board by rote. That kind of rote learning results in unnecessary conceptual compartmentalization that can be very detrimental.

I doubt the situation will improve unless the math departments start showing students both epsilon-delta and hyperreal+Sato approaches. Then students would have the maturity coming from thinking of the motivations for using alternate definitions.

Comment: Interesting reply.  Feel free to elaborate on Sato.

Comment: I think it is very smart to explain how the $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definition captures Newton's and Leibniz's informal notion of an infinitessimal, but I think that actually trying to teach real analysis students about hyperreals is a very bad idea.  Your choices are either to try to define things properly using non-principal ultrafilters or whatever, in which case $\delta$'s and $\epsilon$'s will look like a walk in the park; or wave your hands at the definition, which defeats the whole purpose of a real analysis class.

Comment: @PaulSiegel, I don't think anybody would argue that *analysis* can (or should) be taught without $\epsilon,\delta$ definitions. Rather, we are talking about freshman calculus. Just as you don't construct the real line in freshman calculus, it would be inappropriate to construct the hyperreals. Rather, you define infinitesimals via violation of the Archimedean property, and show students how to work with them rigorously. In my *first hand* experience, they relate to this much more positively than being dressed to perform multiple-quantifier epsilontic stunts on pretense of being taught calculus

Comment: @katz: Hold on, now I'm confused.  The first sentence in the text of your question referred to "definitions in real analysis", and your quote from Dawkins begins with "Student difficulties with real analysis definitions."  Additionally, Jake Shreffler's answer refers to "introductory analysis" classes.  The question about what precise definitions should be taught in a freshman calculus class is a very different one (whose best answer is probably "none"), so if that is what you are asking you should make it clearer in your question.

Comment: @PaulSiegel, Dawkins wrote "both at the calculus and analysis level of instructions". In the title of his section 2.3 he is merely including calculus as part of analysis and using analysis as a general term. Most of the studies he cites have to do with calculus teaching. Kleinfeld's title mentions "calculus" and Bishop is similarly talking about calculus teaching.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is in part due to what we might call **Gromov's zero-one law** (from [this paper on pg. 64](http://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/stability_and_pinching.pdf), and also [quoted in the conclusions here](http://www.ams.org/notices/200003/fea-berger.pdf))...

> ...this common and
>   unfortunate fact of the lack of an adequate
>   presentation of basic ideas and
>   motivations of almost any mathematical
>   theory is, probably, due to the binary
>   nature of mathematical perception: either
>   you have no inkling of an idea or,
>   once you have understood it, this very
>   idea appears so embarrassingly obvious
>   that you feel reluctant to say it aloud;
>   moreover, once your mind switches
>   from the state of darkness to the light,
>   all memory of the dark state is erased
>   and it becomes impossible to conceive
>   the existence of another mind for which
>   the idea appears nonobvious...

Just in case... I'm not saying the math education people don't understand limits :).

Answer (score 5):

I believe that epsilon-delta definition is immediately appealing to students with a certain clarity of mind, who find the heuristic notion of limit vague and confusing. It certainly was the case with me. However, these are a small minority of students in a typical first or second semester calculus course. They may later become math majors and get a serious proof-based education.

At the same time, the majority of students we teach calculus to are NOT going to be mathematicians. It is OK for an engineer to be vague about some foundational notions of mathematics and rigorous definition of a limit is one such notion. We can teach it much the same way a good colloquium or seminar speaker glosses over unpleasant technical details, occasionally at the expense of correctness.

I personally always put the epsilon-delta definition on the board and explain it as best as I can, but with a time cap on the discussion. It is presented as a window into math major experience, rather than a central part of the curriculum. As a middle ground, when I talk about a limit, I make sure to use a catch phrase "wobble subsides" to avoid the common misperception that functions $f(x)$ that have a limit at $x\to a$ are monotone in a small neighborhood of $a$.

Comment: As I note in my comment above, it is exactly engineers who would profit the most from serious attention to $\epsilon-\delta$ in the form of rigorous error analysis.  In every application, you need to know how good a control on inputs you need to guarantee a given error tolerance on the outputs.  Without this bridges collapse, and airplanes fail to get off the ground.

Comment: @Steven Gubkin, I agree with your comment about error analysis -- but I would emphasize that you need a uniform $\epsilon-\delta$ analysis for that application.  E.g.:  What control on the radius do you need to guarantee an error within 1% on the volume?  The application is not good with an answer depending on $r$, the actual and unknown radius; it's better to give the answer from uniform continuity that applies to a range of $r$'s.

Comment: This answer reminds me of how I was taught limits the first time around, which was a kind of middle ground between "total handwaving" and rigorous $\epsilon,\delta$ definitions. Namely I was told, only in words, something along the lines of "$f(x) \to L$ as $x \to a$ if you can make $f(x)$ arbitrarily close to $L$ by taking $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$". This is not 100% unambiguous, but I found it both enlightening and intelligible at the time.

Comment: @Ian, that's a useful heuristic.  Another useful heuristic is in terms of the "trough/target" dichotomy, which I use when I teach this based on infinitesimals as well.

Comment: It is common for us to justify the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ explanation of limits in terms of error tolerance in practical situations. However, there is a key difference. Engineers don't need the first quantifier. They have an a priori value of $\epsilon$ in mind and solve for the $\delta$. They do not need to solve this for every possible value of $\epsilon$.